# What meaning has "the" article in "the more" usage?

Tags: difference, articles, definite-article

Some examples with "the more":

> But some of those kids can hardly read or write! All the more reason
> why they should get the best education on offer.
>
> The more is the better. (But that example is comparative correlative
> construction. It's somehow understandable case).

What's the meaning of this article? What's the difference between "the more" and just "more" ?

And why is the article used without a noun?

Comment: It's a fixed expression. You took this passage from [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-the-more-reason) which says it's used for emphasising the reason.

Comment: It's a "fixed" *construction*. Taught to native speakers at a very early age, with one specific example being what The Big Bad Wolf says to Little Red Riding Hood when she (thinking he is her grandmother) says *"Grandma! What big teeth you've got!"* Whereupon The Big Bad Wolf leaps out of grannie's bed shouting *"**All the better to EAT you with**!"* The construction may have been repeated any number of times immediately before that with *what big legs / ears / eyes ... All the better to run / hear / see / ...,* so it's well and truly "learned by rote".